# Rendering deactivated content elements in fluid template

Tags: typo3, fluid

I want to render a deactivated content element (from another page) in a fluid template. Is there a nice way to do this? Actually I'm using this VHS-Viewhelper:

```
<v:content.render pageUid="xxx" contentUids="{0:xxx}" slideCollect="1">
    <!-- tag content - may be ignored! -->
</v:content.render>
```

but it only works with activated elements.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible this way. Deactivated content elements are never shown.

To archive the same, you can put them into a column that is not displayed on the other page and keep them all enabled. You can then use the `column` attribute to select all elements from a specific column.